# Angular pinterest - not working with binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pinterest

I've implemented angular pinterest - into my one page application, this can be found here:

https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-pinterest/

It all works fine inside of my application using:

```
<pin-board username="'pointblankdev'" board-name="'point-blank-development'" image-width="'200'" board-height="'140'" board-width="'250'"></pin-board>
```

However when i try and implement a data binding into the **board-name** It does not return anything, this is what my code looks like:

```
 <pin-board username="'username'" board-name="'{{getPinBoard}}'" image-width="'267'" board-height="'1149'" board-width="'1149'"></pin-board>
```

and this is inside of my directive:

```
$scope.$watch('getPinBoard', function() {
    var url = $scope.lookName;
    var urlToLower = url.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
     $scope.UrlLower = urlToLower;
 });
```

But just returning:

> {{getPinBoard}}

Gives me the correct board-name.

here is my directive:

```
app.directive('pinterestBoard', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            lookName: '=lookName',
            pinBoard: '=pinBoard',
            columns: '=columns',
            muses: '=muses',
            boardPadding: '=boardPadding',
            boardHeight: '=boardHeight'
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/pinterest.board.html',

        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            var resizeEnded;

            $scope.getPinBoard( function() {
                var url = $scope.lookName;
                var urlToLower = url.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

                 $scope.UrlLower = urlToLower;
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Im not 100% im learning as i go as this is only the second time i've worked with angular and im trying to understand everything.

Comment: It looks like an unusual implementation I must say, why watch the value and do something unrelated in the callback? Either way you need to remove the single quote marks if you want `getPinBoard` evaluated. e.g. `board-name="{{ getPinBoard }}"`. That should move you closer in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, i've given that a go but the console has decided to throw it back at me :(   `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'getPinBoard' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 4 of the expression [{{ getPinBoard }}] starting at [getPinBoard }}].`